# Is using array arguments in C considered bad practice?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference

When declaring a function that accesses several consecutive values in memory, I usually use array arguments like

```
f(int a[4]);
```

It works fine for my purposes. However, I recently read [the opinion of Linus Torvalds](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428).

So I wonder if the array arguments are today considered obsolete? More particularly,

- is there any case where the compiler can utilize this information (array size) to check out-of-bound access, or
- is there any case where this technique brings some optimization opportunities?

In any case, what about pointers to arrays?

```
void f(int (*a)[4]);
```

Note that this form is not prone to "sizeof" mistakes. But what about efficiency in this case? I know that GCC generates the same code ([link](https://godbolt.org/z/5JhWYq)). Is that always so? And what about further optimization opportunities in this case?

Comment: How else would you propose to pass a 2D array to a function? Defining the function argument as an array allows the compiler to index it correctly, whereas defining it as a pointer does not give the compiler enough information. Note that the length of the outer dimension is ignored anyway, so is useless for defining, say, a string length.

Comment: Not passing arrays would make things like strings pretty awkward to use...

Comment: `void f(int (*a)[4]);` and `void g(int a[4]);` are not equivalent. Just `printf("%p\n", (void*)(a + 1));` in each function.

Comment: @WeatherVane Good point (the 2D array). However, I'm afraid this is exactly what Linus meant: `sizeof` operator works as expected for one dimension, and doesn't work as expected for the other one. So, in fact, it could really be misleading.

Comment: As commented, you can't use `sizeof` meaningfully on the function array or pointer arguments, so avoid it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you write

```
void f(int a[4]);
```

that has *exactly* the same meaning to the compiler as if you wrote

```
void f(int *a);
```

This is why Linus has the opinion that he does.  The `[4]` *looks like* it defines the expected size of the array, but it doesn't. Mismatches between what the code looks like it means and what it actually means are very bad when you're trying to maintain a large and complicated program.

(In general I advise people *not* to assume that Linus' opinions are correct.  In this case I agree with him, but I wouldn't have put it so angrily.)

Since C99, there is a variation that *does* mean what it looks like it means:

```
void f(int a[static 4]);
```

That is, all callers of `f` are required to supply a pointer to an array of at least four `int`s; if they don't, the program has undefined behavior.  This can help the optimizer, at least in principle (e.g. maybe it means the loop over `a[i]` inside `f` can be vectorized).

Your alternative construct

```
void f(int (*a)[4]);
```

gives the parameter `a` a different type ('pointer to array of 4 int' rather than 'pointer to int').  The array-notation equivalent of this type is

```
void f(int a[][4]);
```

Written that way, it should be immediately clear that that declaration is appropriate when the argument to `f` is a *two-dimensional* array whose inner size is 4, but not otherwise.

`sizeof` issues are another can of worms; my recommendation is to avoid needing to use `sizeof` on function arguments at almost any cost.  Do *not* contort the parameter list of a function to make `sizeof` come out "right" inside the function; that makes it harder to *call* the function correctly, and you probably call the function a lot more times than you implement it.

Comment: I will refrain from using pointers to arrays, as you recommend. However, I was hoping for some case where this construct brings some other possibilities aside from the code documentation. But there is probably nothing more to say. So I will mark this answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

When you pass an array expression as an argument to a function:

```
int arr[100];
...
foo( arr );
```

what the function actually receives is a pointer to the first element of the array, not a copy of the array.  The behavior is exactly the same as if you had written

```
foo( &arr[0] );
```

There's a rule that function parameters of type `T a[N]` or `T a[]` are "adjusted" to `T *a`, so if your function declaration is

```
void foo( int a[100] )
```

it will be interpreted as though you wrote

```
void foo( int *a )
```

There are a couple of significant consequences of this:

- Arrays are implicitly passed "by reference" to functions, so changes to the array contents in the function are reflected in the caller (unlike literally *every other type*);
- You can't use `sizeof` to determine how many elements are in the passed array because there's no way to get that information from a pointer.  If your function needs to know the physical size of the array in order to use it properly, then you must pass that length as a separate parameter<sup>1</sup>.

In my own code, I do not use array-style declarations in function parameter lists - what the function receives is a pointer, so I use pointer-style declarations.  I can see the argument for using array-style declarations, mostly as a matter of documentation (this function is expecting an array of this size), but I think it's valuable to reinforce the pointer-ness of the parameter.

Note that you have the same problem with pointers to arrays - if I call

```
foo( &arr );
```

then the prototype for foo needs to be

```
void foo( int (*a)[100] );
```

But that's also the same prototype as if I had called it as

```
void bar[10][100];

foo( bar );
```

Just like you cannot know whether the parameter `a` points to a single `int` or the first in a sequence of `int`s, you can't know whether `bar` points to a single 100-element array, or to the first in a sequence of 100-element arrays.

---

1. This is why the `gets` function was deprecated in after C99 and removed from the standard library in C2011 - there's no way to tell it the size of the target buffer, so it will happily write input past the end of the array and clobber whatever follows.  That's why it was such a popular malware exploit.